# What is the most efficient way of moving a UIView on screen with Core Motion?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a simple game where a view on the screen moves according to how the user tilts the device using CoreMotion. I've read on sources on how to do this but a red flag came to mind. Most or all of the sources I've read calls the drawRect: method for updating the display i.e. 'animating' the view onscreen.

I've read docs on CoreAnimation and CoreGraphics from Apple. It said that when it comes to animation, CoreAnimation is the way to go because drawing (calling drawRect: everytime) is expensive since CoreAnimation uses OpenGL in the backend and did some optimizations there.

So I'm a bit puzzled. Am I supposed to use drawRect: or CoreAnimation? And if I should use CoreAnimation, how am I suppose to animate the views on screen with the accelerometer updates? (I haven't read any code using CoreAnimation with CoreMotion before).

Also, I'm only going to use Native Apple Frameworks and not CoCos2d or any other third party frameworks.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: If the need is a simple as moving a view on the screen, you can calculate the desired new location from the `CMAttitude`, then set the `center` property of the view to that point on screen. To make the movement of the view smooth, you will need to update its center point on a regular basis - maybe 60 Hz. You can do this by setting up an `NSTimer`.

Comment: My game is I have a UIImageView that will be controlled by the user through CoreMotion. I'll also be adding another view (Enemy) that will shoot bullets at the user (User can also shoot bullets).

The thing with the NSTimer, I've seen the code for this that it updates the view by updating the frames to new points instead of using core animation to move the frame to the new point... So I guess using CoreAnimation won't be good.